# SetupGet with multiple callbacks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Please see the code below:

```
mockBusinessLayer.Setup(m => m.Calculate(It.IsAny<integer>(), It.IsAny<integer>())).Callback
            (() => mockBusinessLayer.SetupGet(y => y.FirstNumber).Returns(Helper.FirstNumber));
        mockBusinessLayer.Setup(m => m.Calculate(It.IsAny<integer>(), It.IsAny<integer>())).Callback
            (() => mockBusinessLayer.SetupGet(y => y.SecondNumber).Returns(Helper.SecondNumber));
```

Calculate() accepts two integers and adds them together.  How do I setup multiple SetupGets on the same mock object? The above code only sets up the Get callback on SecondNumber (because it is the last time SetupGet is called).

**Update**

This is the function I am trying to test:

```
public CalculatorDTO Calculate(int NumberOne, int NumberTwo)
        {
                _Calculator.Calculate(NumberOne, NumberTwo);
                return Mapper.Map<CalculatorDTO>(_changeCalculator);
            }
        }
```

Is it better to do this:

mockBusinessLayer.Setup(x => x.FirstNumber).Returns(Helper.FirstNumber);
            mockBusinessLayer.Setup(x => x.SecondNumber).Returns(Helper.SecondNumber);

Comment: That is by design. Moq only recognizes the last setup on a member. What is it you are trying to test?

Comment: @Nkosi, is it possible to setup multiple: SetupGet()

Comment: Show what you are trying to test and let's see if we have help solve your problem.

Comment: @Nkosi, I have added an update.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing further setup in the `Callback` method? Why not just setup everything at the onset?

Comment: @ Kenneth K, thanks.  Please see the update to my question.  Is that what you mean by: "setup everything at the onset".  If it is not then please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> The above code only sets up the Get callback on SecondNumber (because it is the last time SetupGet is called).

But that's not quite right: your calls to `Setup` of `Calculate` are identical and thus the second one overrides the first.  It's as if the first `Setup` never occurred.

Putting the calls to `SetupGet` in the `Callback` is unnecessary and confusing.  I'd set it up like this:

```
mockBusinessLayer.SetupGet(y => y.FirstNumber).Returns(Helper.FirstNumber)
mockBusinessLayer.SetupGet(y => y.SecondNumber).Returns(Helper.SecondNumber)
mockBusinessLayer.Setup(m => m.Calculate(It.IsAny<integer>(), It.IsAny<integer>()));
```

Any time `FirstNumber` is gotten, it will return `Helper.FirstNumber`, and likewise for `SecondNumber` returning `Helper.SecondNumber`.

---

All that being said, without more of your code (What type is `_Calculator`? Does your `mockBusinessLayer` really expose `FirstNumber`/`SecondNumber` *and* `Calculate`?) it's hard to offer more complete steps to move forward. For instance, you don't show the setup of your `Mapper.Map` method, which you'll need if you want to test this method.

---

In response to your update...

`SetupGet` offers a slightly cleaner API: you're required to pass a `Func`, while `Setup` will allow you to pass an `Action`; it returns a slightly more restricted `ISetupGet` interface. `SetupGet` also has better semantics, indicating to readers that you intend to set up only the get.

In the Moq source they actually boil down to the same code so either get the job done just as well.

Comment: thank you.  What is the benefit of using SetupGet over Setup? (Please see the update in my question).

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Finally, Kenneth K in his comment (under my OP) says: "setup everything at the onset".  Is this what you have done here or is there a "better" way? Thanks again.

Comment: That's what I've done here.  Setting it all up at once is usually easier to read.  Putting setups in callbacks, while possible and _sometimes_ useful, is strange and difficult to understand.